# Angular2: How to override multiple providers in TestComponentBuilder

Tags: angular

I have tried this, it only takes the first one:

```
.overrideProviders(LongProfile, [provide(AppService, { useClass: MockAppService }),provide(ProfileService, { useClass: MockProfService }),provide(AppService1, { useClass: MockAppService1 })])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issues with an array of providers in `overrideXxx`

The related issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7397 was fixed shortly after RC.1 was published and will be included in the next update.